# status 500 (Internal Server Error) при отправке FormData через xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, formdata

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Нужно отправить файл на сервер через xmlHttpRequest.
Используется FormData.

При отправке файла вылазит ошибка Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

С сервером всё ок, ошибка в моем коде. Но никак не найду где.
Прошу прощения, я новичок, но очень стараюсь.
Буду благодарна за помощь!

Ниже функция отправки файла:

```html
function sendFile(file) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://---', true);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(`Файл ${formData.file.name} отправлен.`);
  }});
  xhr.send(formData);
};
```

Comment: Не может быть с сервером всё ок если он 500 говорит) Если бы ошибка была только в вашем коде - сервер отвечал бы ошибкой 4хх серии

Comment: Я задавала вопрос бекенду, мне сказали, что сервер абсолютно рабочий и проблема на моей стороне. Перечитала кучу информации, пытаясь понять, где косяк. Но так и не нашла его. Только поэтому уже обратилась сюда)

Comment: Рабочий сервер не должен отвечать ошибкой 500. ошибки 500ой серии указывают как раз на ошибки на сервере. 400ые - ошибки в запросе клиента.

Comment: Да, я это знаю. Но учитывая те факты, что мне с уверенностью говорят, что ошибка исключительно только у меня, и что я пока новичок, я сделала предположение, что, возможно, я действительно как-то повлияла на эту ошибку. Может быть такое? Неверно написанный скрипт или формат данных?

Comment: Даже если вы и правда допустили ошибку в запросе - то на сервере тоже допущена ошибка, в обработке вашей ошибки) В любом случае вам нужно пытать бекенда, чтоб он вам сказал что именно не так в вашем запросе. Попросите его предоставить логи)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь! Хорошего дня!)